# Why does a previously installed app get uninstalled in Android when I try to install a new app in Ionic 4.1.1

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to install a new app on my android device through Ionic CLI 4.1.1 for testing the native features. But the previous apps get uninstalled during the process.

Is this because of the same package provided for the app?

Comment: check the `name` of the application in `package.json` in both application it should be same

Comment: Are you using capacitor?

Comment: No i am not using capacitor and btw what does it mean

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the same build id if you want to keep an older version and install new version make sure the `widget id` in config.xml is different for both the apps, if it is same it will uninstall older one and install a new one